# How to fetch the users mapped to specific retailer in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a portal where a **admin** creates reseller. Each reseller can have his own users. So in users table there they are mapped with the **resellerid**. So now i want to show only those users which are of mapped to his **ID** So how to show only those users that are mapped to his account. My save function fetches all the users but instead i want to fetch users for that reseller which is loggedin instead of fetching all the records.
Following is my code for:

Controller :

```
public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/index';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

Model :

```
public function login ()
{
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),

    ), TRUE);

    if (count($user)) {
        // Log in user
        $data = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,


            'id' => $user->id,

            'loggedin' => TRUE,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}

public function logout ()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in','id','name','email');

}

public function loggedin ()
{
    return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
}
```

The Base Model where save function exist.

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }


    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->get(NULL, $single);
}

public function save($data, $id = NULL){




    // Set timestamps
    if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $id || $data['created'] = $now;
        $data['modified'] = $now;
    }

    // Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
        !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    // Update
    else {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
    }

    return $id;
}
```

The View File:

```
<?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>   
    <tr class="info">
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->sip_username); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->sip_password); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->key); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->name); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->status); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->email); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->phone); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->balance); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->created); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->modified); ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/user/edit/' . $user->id); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/user/delete/' . $user->id); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
        </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You are face any problem to fetch record from database?

Comment: Actually my query fetches all the records from database i just want to fetch  those users that are mapped to specific reseller. i mean if reseller-1 is logged in than he can see only his users not others

Comment: Check your where condition then.check codeigniter [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: i have a function loggedin, but i don't know how to use the where condition to check to a loggedin function as i am new to codeigniter

Comment: First of all when a user login.check usertype and include usertype within session.
On behalf of session['usertype'] create if condition.

Comment: Yes that might work, but can the reseller only see his users by this?.

Comment: Yes you can if usertype is reseller then select user where parent-id is equal to reseller id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when a user login.check usertype and include usertype within session.
or

```
public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $id = $session_data['id'];

    $data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get($id)

    // Load view
    $data['subview'] = 'reseller/user/index';
    $this->load->view('reseller/_layout_main', $data);
}
```

Your model `reseller_m.php` code

```
function get($id)
{       
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('tablename');
   $this->db->where('key',$id);
   return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

In your view file

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) { ?>

   <?php echo $test->id;?>
```

Comment: This fetches all the records(users). i just want to show the users created or mapped by the reseller id

Comment: how you identify user under a particular reseller what is the field name in your db.

Comment: in users table i have field "Key" in this i store the resellerid  from which i identify which users is mapped to which reseller

Comment: i know i am getting too much dependent but  i got this error in view file:Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: user/index.php

Line Number: 27 and A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: models/user_m.php

Line Number: 87 in model

Comment: i have updated the view file please check and tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85400/discussion-between-rajan-and-bugfixer).